# How to plot $r^2=3\cos{2\theta}$ using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to draw $r^2=3\cos{2\theta}$ with this code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[dvinames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=2in,left=1.5in,bottom=1.5in,right=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,
        pdfborder={0 0 0},
        ]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]

\fill [yellow, domain=0:2*pi, samples=500, variable=\x]
(-2, 0)
-- plot ({deg(\x)}:{3*cos(2*\x r)})
-- (0, 0)
-- cycle;



\draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};


\foreach \n in {-3,3}{%
    \draw (\n,-0.7pt) -- (\n,0.7pt)   node [below] {$\n$};
    % \draw (-0.7pt,\n) -- (0.7pt,\n)   node [left] {$\n$ };
}
\foreach \n in {-3,3}{%
    % \draw (\n,-0.7pt) -- (\n,0.7pt)   node [below] {$\n$};
    \draw (-0.7pt,\n) -- (0.7pt,\n)   node [left] {$\n$ };
}

\draw[color=orange][domain=0:2*pi,samples=500] plot ({deg(\x)}:{sqrt(3*cos(2*\x r))});

\node [right, orange] at (+1.6,+1.2) {$ r=3\cos{2\theta} $};
\node [darkgray] at (+1.6,+0.4) {$A_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

but errors appeared. What should i do?

Comment: Please include a full compilable MWE. One that includes the `\documentclass` and all of your `\usepackage`s etc.

Comment: I have added those @PTNobel... and then?

Comment: You are using pgfplots wrong, I'll put together an answer soon.

Comment: Should the function be plotted on polar corrdinates?

Comment: Did you look at the error? What is `{sqrt(3*cos(2*\x r))}`? cos(x) has also negative values, so the sqrt does not exist unless you want to show the imaginary part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my effort to draw it. I used two different function `+sqrt(3*cos(2*x)` and `-sqrt(3*cos(2*x))`. The `deg()` around the `2*x` in my code is needed since the `cos()` function only takes values in degrees and `deg()` converts radians to degrees.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[data cs=polarrad, domain=0:2*pi, samples=2500]
    \addplot[] {sqrt(3*cos(deg(2*x)))};
    \addplot[] {-sqrt(3*cos(deg(2*x)))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```